# Passing data through props in Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am fairly new to React.js and recently learned about npm package react-router-dom (5.0.0). I want to pass my data in Dashboard component through props in Route. Something like this (shows error):

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <NavBar/>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} >
        <Dashboard Project={Something}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/createproject" component={CreateProject} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then access it as:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.Project}</h1>
  }
}
```

I would be thankful if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Route `render` prop allows you to render a component inside a Route and pass props to it.

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => <Dashboard project={myProject}} />
```

See the React Router [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/Route/render-func) on this.